# Android Camera2 session creation logic

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am new to Camera2 framework and trying to understand the logic of creation of capture sessions.

I need a simple thing - preview and record video. I also want to set the correct orientation hint **at the time I start recording the video**. But I came to a chicken/egg problem.

Here is my logic:

In order to start recording, I am doing this:

```
    val recordRequest = session.device.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD).apply {
        // Add the preview and recording surface targets
        addTarget(viewFinder.holder.surface)
        addTarget(recorder.surface)
    }.build()

    session.setRepeatingRequest(recordRequest, null, cameraHandler)

    recorder.setOrientationHint(it) // NOT allowed after getSurface()!
    recorder.prepare()              // NOT allowed after getSurface()!
    recorder.start()
```

However, I already called `recorder.surface` (or `getSurface()`) when I added targets above. One can think that I can prepare and then add targets, however, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.Builder#addTarget(android.view.Surface)) for `addTarget()` says, that the surface *The Surface added must be one of the surfaces included in the most recent call to **CameraDevice#createCaptureSession***

---

That leads to an interesting problem. Whenever I open the app, I need to create the capture session to start previewing camera image. However, at the point of creation the [createCaptureSession()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createcapturesession) needs to include **all the surfaces** that will come in future **capture requests**. Which means that I also need to include the recording surface, even if I simply open camera without recording yet. How do I get this `Surface` for recording? Well, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice#createCaptureSession(android.hardware.camera2.params.SessionConfiguration)) says I can get it from `MediaRecorder` or I can get it from `MediaCodec`. I want to get it from `MediaRecorder` since I want to use `CamcorderProfiles`. However, as I showed in the above code, once I get the surface from the recorder **at the point of session creation** - I cannot do any changes there **at the point of starting recording**, like setting orientation hint.

The official [Camera2Video](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/Camera2Video) sample app does a trick - it uses [createPersistentInputSurface](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/Camera2Video/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/video/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L103) however in their example the camera is fixed, which allows them to allocate enough memory for it and use that surface throughout the app lifecycle.

How can this be solved? Am I misunderstanding the concepts here? How can I create the recorder at a later point, when I start recording, but still have the surface for it created earlier, when I open the camera for preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a persistent input surface is the right approach. Create a new MediaRecorder once you know the orientation for recording, and set its Surface using the persistent input surface.

That's exactly what the Camera2Video sample does, [as well](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/Camera2Video/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/video/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L272):

```
        // React to user touching the capture button
        capture_button.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
            when (event.action) {

                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

                    // Prevents screen rotation during the video recording
                    requireActivity().requestedOrientation =
                            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED

                    // Start recording repeating requests, which will stop the ongoing preview
                    //  repeating requests without having to explicitly call `session.stopRepeating`
                    session.setRepeatingRequest(recordRequest, null, cameraHandler)

                    // Finalizes recorder setup and starts recording
                    recorder.apply {
                        // Sets output orientation based on current sensor value at start time
                        relativeOrientation.value?.let { setOrientationHint(it) }
                        prepare()
                        start()
                    }
```

and `recorder` is created with an earlier-created persistent surface:

```
    /** Saves the video recording */
    private val recorder: MediaRecorder by lazy { createRecorder(recorderSurface) 
    }
```

When you say the camera is fixed, do you mean the app orientation being fixed, or that the sample doesn't support switching front/back cameras?  None of that should particularly matter for persistent surfaces; you can create a new one when you switch cameras or change orientations, if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I ended up doing! By "fixed" I meant that the sample code didn't switch cameras or configuration once you enter the fragment and "fix" everything in constructors. I thought that persistent input surface can be created once, but then I realized that I can do the same thing on camera switch what the Camera2 example does on fragment creation/destruction. So every time I'm switching camera I do all possible stopRepeating(), close(), release() on all possible camera/session/surface/recorders and start everything from scratch. And it seems to work!